# I am trying to Select the image the particular post

Tags: wordpress

I am trying the fetch the image uploaded(using add media) in the WordPress custom post but I am getting an empty array.

The code which is provided below I have tried this but I am not getting any solution

```
$attachments = get_posts(array('post_parent' => $post->ID,'post_type' => 'attachment',
                    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
                    'order' => 'ASC',
                    'orderby' => 'menu_order ID'));
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($attachments);
```

I want to get the image which is uploaded in a particular post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
$images =& get_children( array (
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image'
));

if ( !empty($images) ) {
    foreach ( $images as $attachment_id => $attachment ) {
        echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, 'thumbnail' );
    } 
}
```

Comment: Hi, Willam thanks for the reply. I tried the above code but it seems it is not working for me it does not give expected output. The image I have uploaded in the post is different and the image which is shown while viewing post is different. So I created a new post with a new image and it didn't show anything.